# Set multiple setInterval(s) dynamically and store for later access

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

I have a function that runs with setInterval, and it gets the variables from the id of the clicked button. Theres a better way of doing this without having to write all block of switch everytime for a new variable?
It is possible to call setInterval dynamically for a variable?

I don't know how to express this problem, but something like this is possible?
Use an array with the items and call setInterval for the item inside the array?

Something like this:

allitems.wood

and then call allitems[item] = setInterval( function() { gather(allitems[item]); }, time );

This is how I am doing it now, but everytime I include a new item I have to write all the case part again...

```
switch(item){
  case "wood":
    getwood = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
    break;
  case "planks":
    makeplanks = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
    break;
  case "stone":
    getstone = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
    break;
  case "leather":
    getleather = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
    break;
  case "iron":
    getiron = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
    break;
}
```

Comment: You need objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need. The `key` is `item` and the `value` is the interval id that can be used to remove the interval later, if needed.

```js
var intervals = {};
function addItem()
{
    var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
    var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    intervals[item] = setInterval(function(){console.log(item)},time);
    console.log(intervals);
}
```

```html
<input id="item" placeholder="Item">
<input id="time" placeholder="Time">
<button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution, I am selecting your answer because was the first one, but the others works too. Thank you @Vignesh Raja

Answer (score 2):

Your suggested solution is pretty much correct.  You can use bracket notation to access object properties, so you can use a variable to access them dynamically.

The following code will gather wood for 6 seconds, stop that and then start gathering stone (purely for example purposes).

```js
var allItems = {
    wood: 0,
    planks: 0,
    stone: 0
};

var time = 2000;
   
function getItem(item) {
    allItems[item] = setInterval(function() {
        gather(item);
    }, time);
}

function gather(item) {
    console.log("gathering " + item);
}

getItem("wood");

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(allItems.wood);
    getItem("stone");
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Nice example @Archer, thanks for the solution it is pretty similar to what I am doing (I am studying setIntervals and creating a incremental game to learn more).

Comment: No problem - glad to help.  I figured you were making one of those games that swallow people's lives while they sit there waiting for resources to be collected.  I tried to make the example suitable to that scenario.  Good luck with your learning :)

Comment: Thanks @Archer if you are curious here is the test game I am making: https://codepen.io/RogerHN/full/RJxRaE/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use an object if I understand your question correctly.

> Something like this:
>
> allitems.wood
>
> and then call allitems[item] = setInterval( function() {
>   gather(allitems[item]); }, time );

You can achieve this by using an object like so:

```
var allitems = {};
allitems[item] = setInterval( function() { gather(item); }, time );
```

So if your item is "wood", then you can access the "wood" interval by doing the following:

`allitems.wood` or `allitems["wood"]`

Comment: @RogerHN no worries :)